# URL rewrites & Drupal functions

Tags: uri, domain-access, subsites

I have a server that hosts our Drupal 7 development, testing, and production environments:

- /var/www/html/dev
- /var/www/html/test
- /var/www/html/prod

Instead of having dev and test live in subdirectories like http://ourdomain.edu/dev, we want the URLs to be http://dev.ourdomain.edu.

From a Drupal standpoint, is this best accomplished through an .htaccess file in each directory?  Or [in settings.php](https://groups.drupal.org/node/5242)?

At the moment, functions like path_to_theme() aren't working at http://ourdomain.edu/dev since path_to_theme begins with a forward slash.  Consequently, the theme refers to http://ourdomain.edu/sites/all/themes/ourtheme/images/logo.png instead of http://ourdomain.edu/dev/sites/all/themes/ourtheme/images/logo.png

It would be great to know what's considered best practice.

Thanks!

Comment: As @Thomas4019 siad, Drupal handles everything gracefully once you've got the server configured properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Drupal in subdirectory named "dev". Then you need to put `$base_url = 'http://www.example.com'` in your settings.php. You may need to put `RewriteBase /dev` in your .htaccess but generally that isn't necessary for me.

If you want to run Drupal at `http://dev.example.com` that is purely an issue of configuring Apache correctly. Your likely need to change your httpd.conf or similar file to setup virtual hosting. Drupal won't need any changes.